# Local Multiplayer 2d Platformer with 1 keyboard (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Am struggling to make this code work, the rigidbody doesn't work with 2 inputs on same client.

I have found this solution, but since it overides gravity, they started floating and are never coming down.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveArrows : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    float MovementY;
    float MovementX;

    Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        MovementY = 0;
        MovementX = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(MovementX * Speed * Time.deltaTime, MovementY * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            MovementY = 2;

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            MovementX = 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            MovementX = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveWASD : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    float MovementY;
    float MovementX;

    Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        MovementY = 0;
        MovementX = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(MovementX * Speed * Time.deltaTime, MovementY * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            MovementY = 2;

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            MovementX = 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            MovementX = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Once I jump, they stay there, I tried Thread.Sleep but doesn't work on Unity.

I tried Coroutine and also didn't work.

I tried to give enought "wait" time before applying a negative movement on Y with my coroutine.

```
StartCoroutine(Wait());
MovementY= -1;
```

The coroutine was:

```
 IEnumerator Wait()
{
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
}
```

My goal was to give enough time before simulating gravity.

Comment: This doesn't provide enough information to answer the question. Gravity is not overridden in this code, so if you don't have gravity it must be in some configuration on one of your objects. I presume you've also placed these two separate components on two separate objects? While you are correct that you can't use Thread.Sleep inside the game loop, can you be more specific than "doesn't work" for your coroutine - including what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, this are 2 scripts applied to 2 objects, both objects have gravity scale set to 2.
I tried to give enought "wait" time before applying a negative movement on Y with my coroutine.

StartCoroutine(Wait());
MovementY= -1;

The coroutine was:

 IEnumerator Wait()
{
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
}

My goal was to give enough time before simulating gravity.

You can try the scripts on 2 objects yourself, after variable Y is set to 1(aka Jump), it becomes a rocket.

Comment: StartCoroutine does not block the code after it.  The coroutine is started and the movementY is decreased immediately after.  You would need to move the decrease line to the inside of the coroutine, after wait for seconds, in order for the delay to work.

Comment: Will try, I assume its due to being async?

Comment: @hijinxbassist THANK YOU, I totaly forgot Coroutine worked async, am new to Unity.
It worked, can smooth it out but the behavior works for now.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot Coroutine worked Async, therefore I added the "gravity" inside the Async method.

Am leaving the solution here in case you ever want a Local Multiplayer 2d Game.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveWASD : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    float MovementY;
    float MovementX;

    Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        MovementY = 0;
        MovementX = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(MovementX * Speed * Time.deltaTime, MovementY * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            MovementY = 2;
            StartCoroutine(Wait());

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            MovementX = 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            MovementX = -1;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
        MovementY = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider giving _kudos_ to the person who gave you the original help (the comment beneath the question)